# Confusion about which time interval to choose to measure the firing angle

Tags: power-supply, switches, power-electronics, thyristor

The firing angle, as I understand, is defined as $$\alpha=t \times \frac{360}{T},$$
where \$t\$ is the time interval between the beginning of the applied voltage and the beginning of the voltage waveform on the load.

[image]

I tried to simulate the motor speed controller below. [image]

And the scope shows (Green=input, Red=load)
[image]
Which time interval do we have to use in this instance to measure the firing angle? It is somehow confusing because the source voltage and the load voltage start at the time, and there are three time intervals to consider.

Comment: Shouldn't the definition of the firing angle read \$\alpha = \frac{t}{T}\cdot 360°\$?

Comment: I'm confused about your simulation results. The thyristor should only switch on during the positive half-wave. The time between the zero crossing of the voltage and the switching on of the thyristor determines the firing angle.

Comment: "Shouldn't the definition of the firing angle read α=t/T *360°?" Typo, sorry.

Comment: I wonder also why the thyristor is switching on during the negative halfwave. Anyway, L1 and C1 create a delay so it would be better to probe the signal at the node (L1,C1) instead of V1 in order to measure the firing angle.

Answer (score 1):

If your circuit is simulated correctly, it will show the expected behavior. In this case the time \$t\$ defines the firing angle.

[image]